# FusionAuth Pre-Registration Hook

Tags: fusionauth

Is there a FusionAuth equivalent to the Auth0 Pre-User Registration hook?

This hook in Auth0 allows (through adding some trivial script), for example, to collect additional information on sign-up and verify this against some other API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is on the roadmap but not currently available in FusionAuth. If you'd like to open a feature request on GitHub you can use that to track the issue.

https://github.com/FusionAuth/fusionauth-issues/issues

Until this feature is available, you could optionally add additional information to the custom data field on the User or User Registration and once you have authenticated, you can use the JWT to retrieve the entire User object.

https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/apis/login

https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/apis/users